# Eigenspace of $T(A)=A^t$ on $\mathcal M_{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have the map $T(A)=A^t$ as defined for $\mathcal M_{n\times n}$, which represents all $n\times n$ matrices. We know that an eigenvector of $T$ is a non-zero $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that $A^t=\lambda \cdot A$. Since $A$ is non-zero, it has a non-zero entry $a_{ij}$. However, the equation $A^t=\lambda \cdot A$ implies that: $$a_{ji}=\lambda a_{ij} \\ a_{ij}=\lambda a_{ji}$$ Substituting, we have that $a_{ij}=\lambda^2 a_{ij} \implies \lambda^2=1 \implies \lambda= \pm 1$. I have verified this response with other sources, and I am quite certain that it is correct. I am stuck on finding the eigenspace, based on these eigenvalues; I know that an eigenspace is the set of all vectors $v$ satisfying $T(v)=\lambda v$. For an explicit matrix, this is straight-forward, but I am having trouble applying it in a more abstract sense. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You're looking for matrices $A$ such that $A^t = T(A) = 1 \cdot A = A$ or $A^t = T(A) = -1 \cdot A = -A$.  Do these types of matrices look familiar?

Comment: Yes, these represent symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices, respectively. Does that mean that the eigenspace consists of any $n\times n$ matrix of either kind?

Comment: There are two eigenspaces: one for the eigenvalue $1$ and the other for the eigenvalue $-1$.  You correctly characterized them.

Comment: More generally, if $T$ is an isometry, what are possible eigenvalues of $T$?  How are these possibilities realized when the isometry is matrix transposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first consider the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=1$. This is just the set of all A such that $A^T=A$. For any such element, the diagonal entries can be anything they want, while the off-diagonal entries must be equal when reflected along the main diagonal. Thus, our eigenspace is the span of all matrices of the form $E_{ij}+E_{ji}$ (where $E_{ab}$ is a matrix consisting of all zeros except in the (i,j)th position, where there is a 1). To get a basis, consider those positions (i,j) on or above the main diagonal.

Next, the matrices where $A^T=-A$. For diagonal entries, we have $a_{ii}=-a_{ii}$, thus the diagonal is all zeroes. Then for all off-diagonal entries, $a_{ij}=-a_{ji}$. Thus, the eigenspace is the span of all matrices of the form $E_{ij}-E_{ji}$. A basis can be constructed by considering only positions (i,j) strictly above the main diagonal.